# Ambiguous overload for operator+ using conversion

Tags: c++

I got a class with conversions konw -> int, double -> konw:

```
class konw {
    double re, im;
public:
    konw() : re(0.0), im(0.0) {}
    konw(double r, double i = 0.0) : re(r), im(i) {}
    operator int() {return re;}
    konw operator+(konw a) {konw wynik; wynik.re = re + a.re; wynik.im = im + a.im; return wynik;}
};
```

In main I test these conversions using overloaded operator+

```
konw zesp(3.1, 0.6);
int ssuma = zesp + 6;
```

The compiler states a bug while working on the last attached line saying that:

`ambiguous overload for 'operator+' in 'zesp + 6'`

As far as I read, if there are several ways to call an overloaded function, the compiler chooses the shortest one. Of course there should be one and only such way. I could find 2 ways of calling operator+:

1. conversion variable `zesp` konw -> int and calling `operator+(int, int)`
2. conversion constant `6` int->double->konw and calling `konw::operator+(konw)`

1st method is faster than 2nd, so Imo the compiler should choose it and execute, but it states a bug about ambiguous overload instead. Why? Where is a mistake in my process of thinking?

Comment: just a general hint: AFAIK, for binary operators, non-member operators are usually preferrable - then both operands can take "advantage" of implicit conversions...

Comment: ye, I know, it was just a quick code for testing purpose ;)

Comment: "1st method is faster than 2nd" that's not how it works. The rules for overload resolution are complicated and involve ranking conversions and matching argument types.

Comment: Thats why I asked where is a mistake in my process of thinking. 1st method uses only 1 conversion: user conversion. 2nd method uses 2 conversions: firstly standard conversion and later user conversion. If we compare numbers of conversion, its 1:2, but if we compare first steps in both methods, 2nd method has better first step (standard conversion is preferable over user conversion). Thats what I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The choice isn't the "shortest" or "fastest" conversion sequence. The rules are fairly complicated (`[ovr.ics.rank]` in the standard), but in this case both conversion sequences require a user-defined conversion, so they're both "user-defined conversion sequences" and are considered equally good. The additional built-in conversion in the second case doesn't make it any worse.

Comment: I saw the example in a book I read like follows:
1) user conversion only
2) user conversion + standard conversion (in that order)
The compiler chose the first way and it was explained like "first method had shorter way to gain a desired type". I explained it to myself that the compiler compared first steps and both were user conversion. So far we have a draw. But second steps are different, so 1st method won. Now I guess that order of needed conversions has some meaning too. Or maybe now the rules are different that stated in the book, which was released in 2004 I guess.

Comment: If that's what the book says, then the book is not correct (and was not correct in 2004 either). Consider this code: http://ideone.com/tIaKCW. The `Foo1` overload of `bar` requires just a user-defined conversion, whereas the `long` overload of `bar` requires a user-defined conversion to `int` followed by a standard conversion to `long`. Nevertheless, the call is ambiguous.

Comment: That was exactly the same kind of an example like in that book. Looks like that info from the book is out of date nowadays. Thank you a lot.

Comment: sorry to bother u again, but I think I need one explanation more. I read the `[ovr.ics.rank]` u mentioned, but still I cant understand one issue. I understand now, why my example was ambiguous (1st operand was better for function A, whereas 2nd operand was better for function B). I understand, why this code: [link](http://ideone.com/03wDn5) compiles successfully (conversion sequence "user conversion + nothing" is better than sequence "user conversion + standard conversion". But I still cant understand, why your example doesnt compile, even if it looks similar to attached one.

Comment: @Givi: I don't see a similarity. Your linked code is not about overload resolution, it's about what conversion chain is used to get from `A` to `int`. The correct conversion chain is to use `operator int()`.

Comment: Right, I mixed up some things. After some sleep I see it like that: in your code both overloaded functions `bar(long)` and `bar(Foo1)` needs to use some user conversion in their conversion sequences. These user conversions are the "worst types of conversion" in both sequences. So no matter there are some additional "better types" (like standard conversion) or not, the worst type decides, and both sequences have the same worst type, thats why ambiguity. As the result, sequence standard conv + standard conv is a better sequence than user conv + nothing. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler tells you this:

```
int ssuma = zesp + 6;
                   ^
prog.cpp:15:19: note: candidates are:
prog.cpp:15:19: note: operator+(int, int) <built-in>
prog.cpp:10:10: note: konw konw::operator+(konw)
```

because all your compiler sees is:

- *"hey, wait, there is `zesp + 6`, maybe I should use `konw::operator+` and convert `6` to `konw` object"*
- *"wait, I can also convert `zesp` to `int` and use built-in `operator+(int, int)`"*

So you should explicitly tell the compiler which one to use:

```
int ssuma = int(zesp) + 6;
```

Comment: I agree, but I read, if there are 2 possible calls, the compiler states a bug only if these 2 calls has equal "work" to do.